# SQL Server Bulk Import with format file - An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file

Tags: csv, sql-server-2012, bcp, bulk-import

I am testing bulk import from a comma separated csv file to sql server 2012. for this purpose i have created the format file by using BCP utility.

following is the a single row from csv file

```
W42031535,4000111689,Domestic,NOV-DEC 2014,Mustafa Satta S/O Abdul Sattar,"H#31, Block#F, TNT Colony",1-Dec-14,17-Dec-14,0,322,20,342,8380,0,8722,32,8754,"JUL-AUG,14",0,"SEP-OCT,14",0,"NOV-DEC,14",0,8,242,161,0,0,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,0
```

and following is my format file, generated by using BCP utility

```
11.0
34
1       SQLNCHAR            0       100     '","'  1     AccountNo                                        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLNCHAR            0       100     '","'  2     BillNo                                           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLNCHAR            0       100     '","'  3     Category                                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLNCHAR            0       100     '","'  4     Billing_Period                                   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLNCHAR            0       200     '","'  5     Name                                             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLNCHAR            0       0       '","'  6     Address                                          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLNCHAR            0       100     '","'  7     Issue_Date                                       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
8       SQLNCHAR            0       100     '","'  8     Due_Date                                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
9       SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  9     Water_Bill                                       Decimal
10      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  10    Sewerage_Bill                                    Decimal
11      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  11    Aquifer_Charges                                  Decimal
12      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  12    Current_Amount                                   Decimal
13      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  13    Arrears                                          Decimal
14      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  14    Service_Charges                                  Decimal
15      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  15    Payable_within_DueDate                           Decimal
16      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  16    Surcharge                                        Decimal
17      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  17    Payable_after_DueDate                            Decimal
18      SQLNCHAR            0       100     '","'  18    Payment_History_1                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
19      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  19    Paid_1                                           Decimal
20      SQLNCHAR            0       100     '","'  20    Payment_History_2                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
21      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  21    Paid_2                                           Decimal
22      SQLNCHAR            0       100     '","'  22    Payment_History_3                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
23      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  23    Paid_3                                           Decimal
24      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  24    Area                                             Decimal
25      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  25    Water_Rate                                       Decimal
26      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  26    Sewerage_Rate                                    Decimal
27      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  27    Discharge_Basis                                  Decimal
28      SQLNCHAR            0       100     '","'  28    Pump_Size                                        SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
29      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      '","'  29    Ferrule_Size                                     Decimal
30      SQLNCHAR            0       100     '","'  30    Meter_Type                                       SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
31      SQLNCHAR            0       100     '","'  31    Meter_Status                                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
32      SQLNCHAR            0       100     '","'  32    Last_Readin                                      SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
33      SQLNCHAR            0       100     '","'  33    Current_Reading                                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
34      SQLDECIMAL          0       19      "\n"   34    Water_Aquiffer_Charges                           Decimal
```

and here is the SQL

```
BULK INSERT WASA_Bill_Detail 
FROM 'e:\WasaBillRecord.csv'
WITH
(
    KEEPIDENTITY,
    FORMATFILE = 'e:\bill_detail_format1.fmt',
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
    ERRORFILE = 'e:\error.log'
)
```

know when i execute the abve sql following error accour

```
Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Procedure BInsert, Line 10
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Procedure BInsert, Line 10
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Procedure BInsert, Line 10
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

i have tried `ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',` , `ROWTERMINATOR = '\r\n',` and `ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',`. The error is same

any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`BULK INSERT` doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) under examples:

> C. Using line feed as a row terminator
>   The following example imports a file that uses the line feed as a row terminator such as a UNIX output:
>
> ```
> DECLARE @bulk_cmd varchar(1000);
> SET @bulk_cmd = 'BULK INSERT AdventureWorks2012.Sales.SalesOrderDetail
> FROM ''<drive>:\<path>\<filename>'' 
> WITH (ROWTERMINATOR = '''+CHAR(10)+''')';
> EXEC(@bulk_cmd);
> ```
>
> Due to how Microsoft Windows treats text files (\n automatically gets replaced with \r\n).

Alternately, send your text file through a line ending converter (unix2dos, et al) or transfer the file in ASCII mode from whatever server you retrieve it from.